# How to program an event that detects when a file is upload to Yammer?

Tags: yammer

Event That is thrown  when file is upload to Yammer.I am not able to do it with Yammer javascript sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how quickly you need to respond to a file being uploaded. The [Data Export API](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/data-export-api) allows you to download just the files.csv which includes a list of files uploaded. You can consume this to know which new files have been uploaded.